# give approve and reject function to the button and display it in user's dashboard in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to give function to both approve and reject button that is in admin dashboard and display the result in user's dashboard.

here is my admin view

dashboard.php.blade

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Leave Type</th>
            <th>Leave Start date</th>
            <th>Leave End date</th>
            <th>Remark</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
            <th>Decline</th>  
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
              @foreach ($leaves as $leave)          
              <tr>
                <td>{{$leave->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$leave->applied_by->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$leave->type->type}}</td>
                <td>{{$leave->start}}</td>
                <td>{{$leave->end}}</td>
                <td>{{$leave->remarks}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Approve</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Decline</a>
```

AdminLeaveController.php .. Do not have any method yet

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Leave;
use App\Models\LeaveType;
use App\User;

class AdminLeave extends Controller
{
    public function leaveapproval()
    {
        $leaves = Leave::with('type', 'applied_by')->get();
        return view ('admin.dashboard',compact ('leaves'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to create two new routes, one for approving, and the other one for declining.

```
Route::post('/approve/{id}', 'AdminLeaveController@approve')->name('admin.approve')
Route::post('/decline/{id}', 'AdminLeaveController@decline')->name('admin.decline')
```

Now, when you have those routes, you can add them to your buttons:

```
<a href="{{route('admin.approve', $leave->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Approve</a> //pass the id here
<a href="{{route('admin.decline', $leave->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Decline</a> //pass the id here as well
```

After that, you could add a `boolean` column to your `leaves` table, something like status, where 0 would be declined, and 1 would be approved.

All that is left to do, is to create two new methods in your `AdminLeaveController`:

```
public function approve($id){
   $leave = App\Models\Leave::findOrFail($id);
   $leave->status = 1; //Approved
   $leave->save();
   return redirect()->back(); //Redirect user somewhere
}

public function decline($id){
   $leave = App\Models\Leave::findOrFail($id);
   $leave->status = 0; //Declined
   $leave->save();
   return redirect()->back(); //Redirect user somewhere
}
```

Note: code is not tested, let me know if you have any errors.

Comment: hi , in route , ca i know which id do you mean

Comment: If you're reffering to `id` in here `/approve/{id}`, that will be your `$leave->id` that you want to update.

Comment: I sort it out already but I am still getting error as Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/approve/0

Comment: ```Route ::group(['middleware' => ['auth' , 'admin']],function(){
 
    Route::get('dashboard','AdminLeave@leaveapproval')->name('dashboard');
    Route::post('/approve/{id}', 'AdminLeaveController@approve')->name('admin.approve');
    Route::post('/decline/{id}', 'AdminLeaveController@decline')->name('admin.decline');
});

Comment: My bad. Alter the routes definitions so they're GET. If that doesn't help either, let me know, I'll give you a different code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass 0 for 'Approve' and 1 for 'Decline'. In `url` then you need one more method in controller which change state of the column you have saved in database.

Don't forget to put csrf token.

As i am seeing this is simple thing you should try at your own also.